# Pass value from javascript to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

In my MVC web application I have a button on the LyncUser Create view that needs to get the value of 'AddressBookNBo' and pass this to the findEmpSurname in my Staff controller. This action then uses the AddressBookNo to retrieve the Surname value from the Staff model. The Surname value is then used to automaticatically populate the Surname value on the LyncUser create view.

When I debug the app and put a stop on the controller action I can see that AddressBookNo is null. Can you advise what I am doing wrong here please.

findEmpSurname action in Staff...

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult FindEmpSurname(int? AddressBookNo)
{

    var staffDB = new StaffEntities();
    var surnames = staffDB.Staff.AsQueryable();
    if (AddressBookNo != null)
    {
        surnames = surnames.Where(p => p.AddressBookNo == AddressBookNo);
    }

    return Json(surnames.Select(p => new { Surname = p.Surname }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Telerik Kendo UI MVC button that calls the PopTextBox javascript when clicked.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("findEmpSurname")
    .Content("Lookup Surname")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" })
    .Events(ev => ev.Click("PopTextBox"))
 )
```

PopTextBox javascript that gets the value of AddressBookNo, passed this to the controller, and uses the returned value to set the Surname value.

```
function PopTextBox()
{
    var data = { AddressBookNo: $("AddressBookNo")[0].value };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FindEmpSurname","Staff")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var surnameTextbox = document.getElementById('Surname');
            surnameTextbox.value = result;
        }
    })    
}
```

Comment: @zed Should be either `$("#AddressBookNo").val()` or `$("#AddressBookNo")[0].value`, `Node` has no `val()` function.

Comment: Hi, I tried the suggestion however this made no difference.

Comment: Hi, I tried the suggestion however this made no difference. AddressBookNo is still null when I look into the findEmpSurname action within the StaffController. The value I am trying to retrieve from the TextBox is using the following code on the Create view.  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressBookNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })